# Resizing controls on a canvas

Tags: silverlight

I have a Silverlight (v3) application that users can drag controls (e.g. Shapes, Images) onto, change the fill colour, drag around etc

I am looking for the best method to allow the user to click on a control, give a visible indication that the control can be reiszed (e.g. display resize handles) and then handle the resizing.

I have played with a few ways of doing this but I am not sure of the best way to make this as clean/generic as possible - ideally I would like to mark a control as resizable and then have common code implement this.  I have tried 1) adding a ControlTemplate to a control and 2) handling the MouseLeftButtonDown event and adding a new rectangle which surrounds the object and then resizing the original control as this rectangle is resized.

Does anyone have experience of implementing this, some good code resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [Resize Behavior](http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/en-us/ResizeBehavior)